# Selecting data from a table based on conditions with other tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm really unsure how best to go about writing this query. I have 3 tables and I need to run a query pulling data from one, based on conditions in the others.

Tables: surveys, survey_countries, survey_categories

**surveys**:
id | survey_id | network_id

**survey_countries**:
id | survey_id | network_id | country

**survey_categories**:
id | survey_id | network_id | category

(The survey_id in survey_countries and survey_categories relates to the survey_id column in the surveys table as opposed to the id column).

I need to retrieve data from surveys for a specific country and a specific category. Then I need to be able to UNION for other categories, but I guess I can do that later. My attempt:

```
SELECT surveys.*
FROM survey_countries
LEFT JOIN surveys ON survey_countries.survey_id = surveys.survey_id ANd survey_countries.network_id = surveys.network_id
LEFT JOIN survey_categories ON survey_countries.survey_id = surveys.survey_id AND survey_categories.network_id = surveys.network_id
WHERE survey_countries.country = 'GB'
AND survey_categories.category = 'my_category'
GROUP BY surveys.id
```

Thanks!

EDIT: the following seems to work:

```
SELECT s.*, ca.category, co.country
FROM surveys s
LEFT JOIN survey_countries co ON s.survey_id = co.survey_id AND s.network_id = co.network_id
LEFT JOIN survey_categories ca ON s.survey_id = ca.survey_id AND s.network_id = ca.network_id
WHERE ca.category = 'uncategorised'
AND co.country = 'GB';
```

I'm just not sure it's the best way to do it since I need to grab surveys with multiple categories later on?

Comment: You're edited query will work just fine.  You'll just need to replace the equal operator with IN if you have multiple categories and/or countries as the conditions

Answer (score 0):

Without example data and an example output, helping you on this query is very difficult. However..... your 2nd join relates survey_countries with surveys.  I think you mean to join it to the survey_categories.  Also, you have a Group By, with no aggregate functions.  Get rid of it until you have too much information an need to summarize columns

I am not saying this is correct, but it is slightly more 'correct' than yours

```
SELECT surveys.*
FROM survey_countries
LEFT JOIN surveys 
  ON survey_countries.survey_id = surveys.survey_id 
    AND survey_countries.network_id = surveys.network_id
LEFT JOIN survey_categories 
  ON survey_categories.survey_id = surveys.survey_id 
    AND survey_categories.network_id = surveys.network_id
WHERE survey_countries.country = 'GB'
  AND survey_categories.category = 'my_category'
```

(If you can, load up a schema and sample data in sqlfiddle. It will make this problem easier to solve.)

Comment: Thanks - that seems to be working. I've updated my OP with another query that works, pretty much identical to yours. I'm just not sure it's the best way to do it since I need to grab surveys with multiple categories later on?

Comment: Multiple categories: couldn't you use `AND survey_categories.category IN ('cat', 'cat1' , 'cat2')` ?

Comment: Yep - but I need to separate the results. I need X results from each category, so I think I just need to run the query again, which is fair from ideal >.<